# can i use boostrap template into my react native project

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to design my page like [this](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/basic-register-page)

It is possible to use this template for my project or do I have to design using a script?

What is the solution to design a login page?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `bootstrap` in a `react-native` project, `react-native` styling isn't `css`, you have to write your own style or use a `react-native` UI toolkit (e.g. [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements), [native-base](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase)) to help you on your design.

Comment: Yes, you can use pre-styled components (like in UI toolkits) and/or `inline-styles` which looks like css but is not, see [React-native style docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html)